# getting an "org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for a child entity:" when using @Id on super class

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have two classes, a child class which is the entity, and a super class which contains the @Id for the entity; as shown below.

Basically it can't create the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean (code at the bottom) because it can't find the @Id on the super class. However when I remove the super class extension from the child class, it works. Any help appreciated, thanks.

**Super class:**

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class GeneralCampaign {

    @Id
    protected String id;
    protected String campaignName;
    protected String accountId;
    protected String createdBy;
    protected STATUS status;

    public GeneralCampaign(){
        this.id = ("cus-"+ UUID.randomUUID());
        this.status = STATUS.DRAFT;
    }

    public GeneralCampaign(User userid,String accountId) {
        this.id = ("cus-"+ UUID.randomUUID());
        this.createdBy=userid.getId();
        this.status = STATUS.DRAFT;
        this.accountId=accountId;
        //this.isEditing = false;
    }

    public GeneralCampaign(String campaignName, String accountId, User user) {
        this.id = ("cus-"+ UUID.randomUUID());
        this.campaignName = campaignName;
        this.accountId = accountId;
        if (user != null)
            this.createdBy = user.getId();
    }

    // getter, setters
}
```

**Child class:**

```
@Entity(name = "local_search_campaign")
public class LocalSearchCampaign extends GeneralCampaign {

    @Column(name = "start_date")
    private Date startDate;
    @Column(name = "end_date")
    private Date endDate;
    @Column(name = "time")
    private java.util.Date timeStamp;
    @Column(name = "campaign_guard_level")
    private Integer campaignGuardLevel = 4;

    @Column(name = "campaign_guard_enabled")
    private Boolean campaignGuardEnabled;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "local_search_campaign_keyword",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "local_search_campaign_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
            )
    @Column(name="keyword")
    private List<String> keywords = new ArrayList<>();
    @OneToMany(
            mappedBy="localSearchCampaign",
            orphanRemoval = true,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY
            )
    private List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private STATUS status;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "campaign", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private LocalSearchPayment campaignPayment;
    @Column(name="landing_page_choice")
    private String landingPageChoice;
    @Column(name="landing_page_URI")
    private String landingPageURI;
    @Column(name="last_updated")
    private java.util.Date lastUpdated;
    @Column(name="is_editing",columnDefinition="default 0")
    private boolean editing = false;
    private String discountCode;

    public LocalSearchCampaign() {
        super();
        //this.id= ("LOC"+UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        this.timeStamp = new java.util.Date() ;
        //this.status=STATUS.DRAFT;

    }

    public LocalSearchCampaign(User userid,String accountId) {
        super(userid, accountId);
        /*this.id = ("cus-"+ UUID.randomUUID());
        this.createdBy=userid.getId();
        this.status = STATUS.DRAFT;
        this.accountId=accountId;*/
        //this.isEditing = false;
    }

    public LocalSearchCampaign(String campaignName, String accountId, User user) {
        super(campaignName, accountId, user);
        /*this.campaignName = campaignName;
        this.accountId = accountId;
        if (user != null)
            this.createdBy = user.getId();*/
    }

    // getter, setters
}
```

**I am creating a `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` as shown below**

```
@Bean
@Primary
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean userEntityManager() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(userDataSource());
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.packagename.etc"});

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect",env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hibernate.dialect"));
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto",env.getProperty("spring.datasource.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    //properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
    //properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
    return em;
}
```

When I don't use the `userEntityManager()` method above and just use the default, it seems to be able to find the `@Id` of the super class.

Comment: Why do you need to have this custom bean `userEntityManager` ? You can set those properties through spring, maybe your `setPackagesToScan` value is the reason, how about putting both packages of `LocalSearchCampaign` and `GeneralCampaign` explicitly in the `String[]`, or just don't set this value, to have the default scanning? Because it does not say the root for the scan, but the explicit target for scan, maybe ignoring anything in subpackages?

Answer (score 0):

Check if your parent class is in package com.packagename.etc.
It seems that it could not found it , 
also you can set just :

```
 em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "*"});//to scan all pacakges
```

Comment: Hi, the parent class is within that package but it still does not work.

Comment: Child class is in the same  or in subpackage or not?

Comment: they're both in the same package, I also tried explicitly scanning the General Campaign package too but still the same issue.